# MySQL query rows with same value in one column and different value in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find the store that sells only 1 specific product

I have to join 3 tables to get all information
This is what the joined table looks like

```
Store | Product | 
----------------
A     | Juice   | Mon
A     | Milk    | Mon
A     | Milk    | Tue
B     | Juice   | Mon
B     | Beer    | Tue
B     | Milk    | Wed
B     | Beer    | Thu
C     | Beer    | Mon
D     | Beer    | Thu
D     | Beer    | Fri
```

I want to get stores that **ONLY** sell Beer, which is obviously C and D in this case.
How do I write a query that can filter out these stores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select store
from t
group by store
having min(product) = max(product);
```

Answer (score 0):

First group according to Store, then check number of products sold by store.

```
SELECT Store, Count(Product) AS pcount
FROM joined_table 
GROUP BY Store
HAVING pcount=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT store
FROM (<your query here>) t
GROUP BY store
HAVING SUM(product <> 'beer') = 0;
```

The condition `SUM(product <> 'beer') = 0` filters out any stores that sell anything different than `'beer'`.